# Error when compile a C++ file with boost/python included

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to run my program below

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <Python.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
        Py_Initialize();

    namespace p=boost::python;
    try
    {
        p::object my_module = p::import("emb");
        p::object dog = my_module.attr("Dog")();
        dog.attr("bark")("eeelllll");
    }
    catch(const p::error_already_set&)
    {
            PyErr_Print();
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with emb.py

```
class Dog():
    def bark(self, message):
        print "The dog barks: {}".format(message)
```

Once I complied it with the following:

```
g++ main2.cpp -I /usr/include/python3.6m/pyconfig.h -I /usr/include/python3.6m/ -lpython3.6m -lboost_python
```

it gives me the following error:

```
cc1plus: warning: /usr/include/python3.6m/pyconfig.h: not a directory
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyString_Size'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS4_FromEncodedObject'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyFile_FromString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyString_Type'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyInt_Type'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyString_FromString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS4_AsWideChar'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyString_FromStringAndSize'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `Py_InitModule4_64'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyString_FromFormat'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyNumber_Divide'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyNumber_InPlaceDivide'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyInt_AsLong'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyString_InternFromString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyClass_Type'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyString_AsString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyInt_FromLong'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so: undefined reference to `PyFile_AsFile'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After I tried to include and exclude many more file in the compiling line, it still doesn't work.
Anyone can help me out, I would be very much obliged.

Comment: drop the `-I /usr/include/python3.6m/pyconfig.h`. Also, remove the space in the other one -> `-I/usr/include/python3.6m`

Comment: @JHBonarius, that works! Thank you. Any reason why the first one need to be dropped?

Comment: the `-I` flag for the compiler is to add a directory to search for included files. You are using it for a specific file, which is not correct. individual files to be included should be added in the source, like `#include <Python.h>`. And because you include this specific `Python.h` file, you don't need to include `pyconfig.h` as it is already added. [just look at the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Include/Python.h).

Comment: @JHBonarius one more question, when I tried to include -lboost_numpy3 or -lboost_numpy to the compiler, i.e. `g++ main2.cpp -I$(VIRTUAL_ENV)/include/python3.6m/ -L $(VIRTUAL_ENV)/lib/ -lpython3.6m -lboost_python -lch -lboost_numpy3`, it shows `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_numpy3`. Is there any directory I need to add more?

Comment: did you run `sudo apt -y install libboost-python-dev`?

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, I did. Tried to include the all possible directories but still doesn't work.

Comment: If you install the packages like that, you don't need to link those directories yourself. Can you look if `sudo apt -y install libboost-numpy3-dev` works? Else try `sudo apt -y install libboost-numpy-dev`

Comment: @JHBonarius the both of commands return `Unable to locate package`. I have also tried  `sudo apt-get install libboost-numpy1.65-dev` and it returns the same result 

Comment: Ok, before we go on: does the compilation work if you remove the part `-lboost_numpy3`?

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes. It works well without that.

Comment: Ok. Then you're done. Please open a new question if you run into new problems.

Comment: @JHBonarius Noted. Thank you very much for the answer for this thread issue.